# Dimension of tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

In some contexts, tensor product $V\otimes W$ is defined as quotient space of the free vector space over $V\times W$ modulo a constructed subspace $N$, i.e.,

$$\pi: F_{V\times W}\to F_{V\times W}/N=V\otimes W.$$

Suppose that both $V,W$ are finite dimensional. I have problems in understanding the dimension relationship among these spaces, though I don't know how to state the question properly.

For quotient space, we have $\dim(F)=\dim(N)+\dim(F/N)$, the issue here is that it seems that $\dim(F)=\infty$, so the relation may be not applicable?

By $\dim(F/N)=\dim(V\otimes W)=\dim(V)\dim(W)$, together with the relation w.r.t. quotient spaces, it implies that $\dim(N)=\infty$...

Can you please clarify the situation, regarding the involvement of $\infty$ here?

Comment: Indeed, everything you wrote is correct, $\dim(F)$ and $\dim(N)$ are both infinite if you work over an infinite field, and this dimension is the cardinal of the field.

Comment: @CaptainLama $\dim F$ and $\dim N$ need not be infinite ($V$ and $W$ may be finite). Even if $\dim F$ is infinite, it need not be equal to the cardinality of the field. For example, if $V$ and $W$ both have dimension $2^{\max\{c,\aleph_0\}}$ (with $c$ being the cardinality of the field), then $\dim F$ is infinite and $\dim F = \lvert V \times W \rvert = 2^c > c$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I said "if the field is infinite" so $V$ and $W$ can't be finite (unless they're $0$). And yes, $\dim(F)$ is always the cardinality of the field, because $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional by hypothesis.

Comment: @CaptainLama That'll teach me to skim. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $\dim A = \dim B + \dim (A/B)$ is true for all vector space inclusions $B \leq A$, regardless of finite-dimensionality (where the dimension of a vector space is understood to be the common cardinality of its bases). You're right though that this fact isn't useful here. What is true is the following:

$$\dim (V \otimes W) = (\dim V) (\dim W)$$

To prove this, let $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a basis for $V$, $\{f_j\}_{j \in J}$ be a basis for $W$, and show that $\{e_i \otimes f_j\}_{(i,j) \in I \times J}$ is a basis for $V \otimes W$.